# Detach tmux session w/ debugging program inside bash script

Tags: bash, session, scripting, tmux

I have a script I want to run where I would start up two programs running inside of separate tmux sessions. The script I have now is pretty much:

```
!/bin/bash
tmux new -s test1 'mono --debug program1.exe'
tmux new -s test2 'python program2.py'
```

The problem I am having is the 2 programs are running in debug mode so they are actively outputting information to the tmux session. I'm not able to gain control to type anything into the tmux session after starting the program. I can however manually detach the session using the `Ctrl + b d` method. I'm not sure how to go about doing that in a bash script though.

I found the `tmux detach` command but since I am not sure how to type into the session after the program has started and debug information is being output I have no way of entering that command.

I also found one post that was saying there is a `-d` flag you can use for tmux that will start a session detached and I was hoping I could do something like `tmux new -d test1 'mono --debug program1.exe'` but that didn't seem to work. It seemed to complain about syntax in the `-d` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add the `-d` flag to each `new` command, in addition to its other options.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new -d -s test1 'mono --debug program1.exe'
tmux new -d -s test2 'python program2.py'
```

Note that you now have two sessions, either one of which you could attach to with `tmux attach -s test1` or `tmux attach -s test2`. It might be simpler to run each command in a separate window of the *same* session:

```
tmux new -d -s test1 'mono --debug program1.exe'
tmux new-window 'python program2.py'
tmux attach -t test1
```

Replace `new-window` with `split-window` to run the commands in separate panes in the same window.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for what I needed. I guess in my haist I was overlooking the fact that the -s flag was still needed in addition to the -d flag. I also had a problem with my path to my program as I did not notice it was dependent upon the location of the script unless I was specific to give the whole path.

Comment: One thing I was wondering if it is possible to do the new-window or split-window commands but ending up detached. Like right now if I try the split-window command with tmux attach -t test1 at the end of the script I end up seeing my tmux window with both programs running. Instead I'd like to see a fresh terminal window, or even better nothing at all. With that session running detached similar to the first example you gave but where both programs run in separate sessions. If not I can go back to separate sessions but I kind of liked split-window now that you showed me that is possible.

Comment: Every `tmux` command affects the `tmux` server (which manages sessions), a given `tmux` session, and/or a `tmux` client. Also, the action of a command depends on whether it is run from inside or outside a `tmux` session. The `new-session` command, for instance, both instructs the server to create a new session *and* starts a new client attached to that session. The `-d` option prevents a new client from being started. The `attach` command, if run from outside an attached session, will start a new client and attach to a session; otherwise, it switches the current client to a new session.

Comment: In other words, you don't have to attach to the session you just created; you can create a new one, or create yet another window and make that the current window before you attach to the session.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I see what you mean now. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

To launch two separate sessions each running a program or command, without attaching, try writing this in your `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmux \
    new \
        -d \
        -s test1 \
        'mono --debug program1.exe' \
    \; \
    new \
        -s test2 \
        -d \
        'python program2.py'
```

### Explanation

- `\` is for line continuation in bash, a good practice to break an otherwise long command to see it more clearly by having each option on its own line.
- `\;` to allow us to add another tmux command to our original tmux call instead starting another tmux call form bash
- `-d` to run the session detached. Its placement as you can see is flexible as long as it is after the `new`
- `new` is an alias, short for `new-session`

So when you run the script, for example

```
$ ./script.sh
```

It quietly starts these tmux sessions. You can check they exist:

```
$ tmux ls
test1: 1 windows (created Sun Mar 13 15:19:31 2016) [79x18]
test2: 1 windows (created Sun Mar 13 15:19:31 2016) [79x18]
```

And attach to view them, for example `test1`:

```
$ tmux attach -t test1
```

Comment: Thank you for being so clear in your example and also providing details as to what was being done syntactically. I did end up going with the other answer's code as it seems more readable but I appreciate that you provided an answer that did exactly what I was looking for.